# How to install custom module and its dependencies with composer in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-modules, drupal-8

Hi I am trying to setup my new Drupal 8 site with composer, but I got few issues.

I tried to setup the site site by following the Guide from [here](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) and was able to setup the site successfully.

After that I tried to install a custom module which is hosted on Bitbucket and I am able to download the package using composer, but the problem is the module has some other contributed module dependency but the dependency module is not downloaded along with the custom module.

I followed the guide from [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-composerjson-file) and added composer.json file to my custom module along with the dependency but after running `composer require custom/custom_module` only the custom module is installed but not the dependency.

My root directory composer.json file repositories section looks like this :

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "custom/custom_module",
        "version": "master",
        "type": "drupal-custom-module",
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "git@bitbucket.org:username/custom-module.git",
          "reference": "master"
        }
      }
    }
],
```

and the composer.json file from the custom module looks as below :

```
{
    "name": "custom/custom_module",
    "description": "This is a Custom Module with Different functionalities.",
    "type": "drupal-custom-module",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "drupal/restui": "~1.16"
    }
}
```

I also chaged the line `"drupal/restui": "~1.16"` as `"drupal/restui": "^1.16"` but with no success.

I even tried running `composer update` in the custom module directory as I was not sure whether dependencies will be installed along with custom module.

After running `composer update` in the custom module directory I got the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package drupal/restui could not be found in any version, the                                                                                                                re may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min                                                                                                                imum-stability setting
>      see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more det                                                                                                                ails.
>    - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further commo                                                                                                                n problems.

But on Drupal.org I can find the module with that version [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/restui/releases/8.x-1.16)

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Try to use `vcs` repository instead of `package` - `package` has man limitations and constantly confuses people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Root composer.json section

```
 "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@bitbucket.org:username/custom-module"
    }
  ],
```

Module composer.json example that has two modules as dependency

```
{
  "name": "username/custom-module",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "type": "drupal-custom-module",
  "description": "Custom module",
  "keywords": ["Drupal"],
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": ">=1.2",
    "drupal/chosen": ">=2.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but still same issue, dependent modules are not being rendered.

Comment: @miststudent2011 what do you mean by "not being rendered"? Not downloaded?

Comment: @miststudent2011 the structure I posted should be correct, but it might be something else. Can you plese share your updated code (the project and module composer?). Also can you try to clear composer cache (composer clear-cache) and confirm that your module are not in vednor folder after you requre it again?